# This function will not work if executed through a Time-driven Trigger, but works ok if called manually

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I got this code for grouping rows. When I call the function manually it works fine. But when I use a Time-driven trigger to execute it won't work. The `console.log()` messages I use to debug show up on the logs. The Time-driven triggers do not display any error nor do I get any email from Google warning me of any errors. It just won't group the rows. In fact after the function gets called through a Time-drive trigger is shows up as `completed`.

Is there some line of code that screws up the Time-driven trigger calls?

Here's the code:

```
const logSheetName = "LOG";

// Functions to group by day, month and year. Within each the variables are redefined, except logSheetName

// Grouping by Day
function groupDays() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    // Variables needed to get row number of the first row of row block for last day, for rowStart variable
    var dateDay = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();
    var dayPlusMonth = Utilities.formatDate(dateDay, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YYYY");
    var cells = sheet.getRange("A5:A").createTextFinder(dayPlusMonth).findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
    var firstRowOfDay = cells[0];
    // Variables needed for Grouping Function
    rowStart = firstRowOfDay;
    rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    dates = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    // Group by day execution
    groupDates(dates, 'date');
    console.log("groupDays() executed");
    console.log("first row from Days position is " + rowStart);
}

var rowStart;
var rows;
var dates;
var prevDate;
var rangeStart;
var rangeEnd;
var groupingPeriod;

function groupDates(dates, period) {
    groupingPeriod = period;
    dates.forEach((date, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
            processInitialDate(date);
        } else {
            processDate(date, idx);
        }
    });
}

function processInitialDate(date) {
    prevDate = date;
    rangeStart = 0;
    rangeEnd = rangeStart;
}

function processDate(date, idx) {
    if (periodHasChanged(date, prevDate, groupingPeriod)) {
        createGroup();
        rangeStart = rangeEnd + 1;
        rangeEnd = rangeStart;
    } else {
        rangeEnd++;
        if (idx === dates.length - 1) {
            createGroup();
        }
    }
    prevDate = date;
}

function periodHasChanged(currDate, prevDate, period) {
    switch (period) {
        case 'year':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getYear();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getYear();
            break;
        case 'month':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getMonth();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getMonth();
            break;
        case 'date':
            var currPeriod = currDate.getDate();
            var prevPeriod = prevDate.getDate();
            break;
    }
    return currPeriod !== prevPeriod;
}

function createGroup() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeGroup = dates.slice(rangeStart, rangeEnd + 1);
    if (rangeGroup.length > 1) {
        var range = `${rowStart + rangeStart + 1}:${rowStart + rangeEnd}`;
        sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    }
}
```

Here is dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just realised in time-driven triggers `getActiveSheet()` won't work. Sheet sheets to be called by name: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LOG");`

At the bottom I changed to:

```
function createGroup() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    var rangeGroup = dates.slice(rangeStart, rangeEnd + 1);
    if (rangeGroup.length > 1) {
        var range = `${rowStart + rangeStart + 1}:${rowStart + rangeEnd}`;
        sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    }
}
```